# Is packages.config required in a deployed asp.net mvc solution

Tags: nuget, packages.config

I did a build publish to a mvc applications and See that packages.config is also deployed even though i did select "Only files required to run this application" in the properties. Can i safely remove this nuget package list file using wpp targets when deploying ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes you can remove it from the deployed application.

It is used by NuGet to keep a record of what NuGet packages are installed in a particular project.

Comment: Why does the `Publish` place a copy of `packages.config` into the Publish directory?

Answer (score 11):

By default, the build process copies all files from source to the destination directory. To exclude the file, right click the file, select properties and for Build Action choose 'None'.